# How can i access the tag of button in CollectionView's cell contained in TableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, tableview, collectionview

I'm working on a project in which i have a `UICollectionView` in `UITableViewCell.` My View hierarchy is like below:

- TableViewCell

  - CollectionView

    - CollectionView Cell

      - Button(for which i want to access the know the tagValue).

I have two table view cell and in each tableView cell there is a `UICollectionView` And each `UICollectionView` contain 4 `UICollectionViewCell`, So i want to know the exact tagValue of my button contained within a `UICollectionViewCell` whenever it is pressed.
I have also given the tag value to button in **cellForItem atIndexpath TableView cell class** like so

```
cell.button.tag = indexpath.item
```

and i have also given selector to the button.

Comment: from where you want to access that collection view cell ? I mean from which class and method ?

Comment: Your tag should be like this -> `(tableviewcell.indexpath.row + 1)*100 + colCell..indexpath.row + 1`

Comment: @Lion i'm accessing the collectionView cell from inside the table View cell class.

Comment: Actually you should have pass data to collection view from cellforrow of tableview! so you can access that data in collection view delegate!

Comment: I'm newbie in ios development, thats why i don't how can i pass data to the collectionView from the cellForRow of tableView.. Could you please suggest me to this ? Or just give me a sample code for ...cellForRow method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

Remove this line :

```
cell.button.tag = indexpath.item
```

**Add this fuction**

```
 @IBAction func clickCollectionCellButton(sender : UIButton){
            var cell: UICollectionViewCell? = (sender.superview?.superview as? UICollectionViewCell) //track your view hierarchy
            var indexpath: IndexPath? = collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell!)
           // do your additional work
        }
```

Comment: in which class i will make this action.

Comment: at that class where you need to click your button.

Answer (score -1):

No need to assign tag value you can directly get cell indexPath in your button exist

suppose you assign a selector to your button like this:-

```
@IBAction function buttonAction(_ sender:UIBUtton){
      if let indexPath = viewIndexPathInCollectionView(sender , collView:pass your collectionView here){
         // here you will get indexPath of your collectionView Cell
         print(indexPath.item)  
      } 
}
```

use this function to get index of collection view  cell by passing cell item in this function

```
func viewIndexPathInCollectionView(_ cellItem: UIView, collView: UICollectionView) -> IndexPath? {
    let pointInTable: CGPoint = cellItem.convert(cellItem.bounds.origin, to: collView)
    if let cellIndexPath = collView.indexPathForItem(at: pointInTable){
        return cellIndexPath
    }
    return nil

}
```